# String with new lines stored in a meteor collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have some paragraphs entered by users stored in a string in a collection but the string has some rough formatting with new line characters. When I present that same paragraph later after accessing it from the collection, how do I have it retain that formatting? If I have the data object and I just do `{{ data_paragraph }}` it ignores the newlines and just spits out the string.

Is there a way to retain this formatting better when I reprint the data to the user?

Edit  -

Here is some additional information :

The text paragraph I am trying to present formatted is just a `textarea` input through Autoforms. People might post a paragraph with `\n` characters but  the whole string is getting stored in the collection.

Just as an example I pass the data in through Iron-Router :

```
SingleParagraphController = BaseController.extend({
    template : 'singleParagraphPage',
    waitOn : function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('singleParagraph', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function() {
        return Paragraphs.findOne({_id : this.params._id});
    }
})
```

And then I want to be able to access the individual paragraph like :

```
<template name="singleParagraphPage">
    <h2> {{ name }} </h2>
    <p> {{ paragraph }} </p>
</template>
```

But it needs to have the same formatting with the new lines when they entered it initially into the text area. The new lines are stored in the string but when I just do it like above its just spits out the string and ignores it.

Comment: what do you mean by rough formatting ? how  `{{ data_paragraph }}` get printed into the template? its possible to check the string formatting before insert it into the collection?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are storing some text from a textarea and got all new lines replaced by the "\n" character in MongoDB. 
To retain formatting and especially new lines when using this text in your html template you can just wrap your data in a `<pre>` tag like this:

```
<pre>
  {{data_paragraph}}
</pre>
```